# MediaPlayer doesn't play after being stopped

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I created an application with three buttons, to play, pause and stop. When I click the button stop and then click play it doesn't play anything. What should i do?

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1,button2,button3;
    MediaPlayer mpUkulele, mpDrums;
 //   int playing;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);




            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

            button1.setOnClickListener(bPlay);
            button2.setOnClickListener(bPause);
            button3.setOnClickListener(bStop);

            mpUkulele = new MediaPlayer();
            mpUkulele = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ukulele);
            mpDrums = new MediaPlayer();
            mpDrums = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.drums);

         //   playing = 0;


        }

        Button.OnClickListener bPlay = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Songs);
                int pos=spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch (pos)
                {
                    case 0:
                        mpDrums.start();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        mpUkulele.start();
                        break;

                }

            }


        };

        Button.OnClickListener bPause = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Spinner spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Songs);
                int pos2=spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch (pos2)
                {
                    case 0:
                        mpDrums.pause();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        mpUkulele.pause();
                        break;
                }

            }


        };

    Button.OnClickListener bStop= new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Spinner spinner3=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Songs);
            int pos3=spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition();
            switch (pos3)
            {
                case 0:
                    mpDrums.stop();
                    mpDrums.reset();

                    break;

                case 1:
                    mpUkulele.stop();
                    mpUkulele.reset();

                    break;

            }

        }


    };
    }
```

I'm able to stream audio and stop it without any problem, but when I try to start it again after stop, it doesn't start and I don't get to play the music again. Hope if there is a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **prepare** the MediaPlayer so it can play again. So basically add this code to every media player you have.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            prepare();
        }
    });

public void prepare() {
    if (mediaPlayer!= null) {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: And don't forget to release it when you are not going to use it anymore.

Comment: Where exactly do I add the code? I have the media player as mpUkulele and mpDrums

Comment: after initiating
            mpUkulele = new MediaPlayer();
mpUkulele.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            prepare();
        }
    });

And do it for both initializations